# Using semaphores to avoid race-condition

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, semaphore, race-condition

I had to create a race condition program using processes and so did I. Now, I am trying to solve it using semaphores. I've got two critical sections and I am trying to secure them using the semaphore I create in `initStem()` using `semctl()`.
`P()` and `V()` increment and decrement the mutex of the semaphore specified in their second parameter.

Unfortunately, it seems that my race condition is still there : My output is :

```
value in parent: 4
value after child exec: 4
```

When it should be :

```
value in parent: 4
value after child exec: 5
```

(5 + 1 - 1 = 5...)

Here is my code :

```
#define KEY 4567
#define PERMS 0660
#define ID_PROJ "race"
#define NB_SEMAPHORES 1

int initSem(char **argv);
int P(int semid, int semnum);
int V(int semid, int semnum);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int id, pid1;
    int *shared;
    int tmp;

if ((id = shmget(KEY, 2*sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | PERMS)) == -1) {
    perror("shmget");
    exit(-1);
}

shared=(int *)shmat(id, NULL, 0);
shared[0]=5; // value
shared[1]=initSem(argv); // semaphore id

if ((pid1=fork()) == 0) {
    P(shared[1], 0); // Start critical section
    tmp=shared[0];
    tmp++;
    sleep(2);
    shared[0]=tmp;
    V(shared[1], 0); // End critical section
    exit(0);
}
else {
    P(shared[1], 0); // Start
    tmp=shared[0];
    tmp--;
    sleep(4);
    shared[0]=tmp;
    V(shared[1], 0); // End

    printf("value in parent: %d\n", shared[0]);

    waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);
    printf("value after child exec: %d\n", shared[0]);
    shmctl(id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
}
}
```

**So I am wondering** : am I using my semaphore correctly ? Am I doing it right by using the same semaphore in both of my processes ?

Edit :

Here are the 3 functions I am using to interact with my semaphores:

```
int initSem(char **argv) {
    int i,semid;
    key_t key=ftok(argv[0], 'P');
    semid=semget(key, NB_SEMAPHORES, IPC_CREAT | PERMS);
    for(i=0 ; i<NB_SEMAPHORES ; i++)
            semctl(key, i, SETVAL, 1);
    return semid;
}

int P(int semid, int semnum) {
    struct sembuf op;
    op.sem_num=semnum;
    op.sem_op=-1;
    op.sem_flg=0;
    semop(semid, &op, 1);
}

int V(int semid, int semnum) {
    struct sembuf op;
    op.sem_num=semnum;
    op.sem_op=1;
    op.sem_flg=0;
    semop(semid, &op, 1);
}
```

Comment: I can't help you with semaphores if you don't post the code that interacts with the sephamores.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question with the code of the missing functions.

Comment: Why don't use classics `sem_init`, `sem_post` and `sem_wait`?

Comment: Because I was explicitly asked to do it using semget and semctl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was in `initSem` where I used

```
semctl(key, i, SETVAL, 1);
```

instead of

```
semctl(semid, i, SETVAL, 1);
```

Otherwise my code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to create the semaphore using [`sem_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sem_init.html) with `pshared` set to nonzero

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to use semget and semctl to achieve this. I updated my question with the code of the missing functions.